# how to use python to check if subdomain exists?

Tags: javascript, python, subdomain

Does anyone know how to check if a subdomain exists on a website?

I am doing a sign up form and everyone gets there own subdomain, I have some javascript written on the front end but I need to find a way to check on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Do a curl or http request on subdomain which you want to verify, if you get 404 that means it doesn't exists, if you get 200 it definitely exists

Answer (score 0):

Put the assigned subdomain in a database table within unique indexed column. It will be easier to check from python (sqlalchemy, pymysql ect...) if subdomain has already been used + will automatically prevent duplicates to be assigned/inserted.